# Different initializing elements in class

Tags: java

I got the code from the internet, now my question is: Why "next" is initialized with SLLNode but the "element" is initialized with E. Whats the difference between them, why and when we use each of them?
Thank you in advance

Here my code:

```
public class SLLNode<E> {
    protected E element;
    protected SLLNode<E> next;

    public SLLNode(E element, SLLNode<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return element.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linked list contains many nodes, in your example of class `SLLNode<E>`. Each node has a reference to a subsequent node (once again, of type `SLLNode<E>`) and each node contains - usually unique - information. This can be anything; in your code they call this piece of information `element` of class `E`. The class `E` can really represent anything.

As an example, imagine a company that offers tours around a city. The tour consists of 5 highlights around town. In order to keep track of the order at which these highlights are visited, one could implement a singly linked list with nodes of class `Highlight<String>`. Each highlight would point towards the next highlight, and each highlight contains a description about the highlight embedded into a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

So we know `int` is a datatype that stores number `boolean` is a datatype that stores true/false `char` is a datatype that stores a single Character.
So in `LinkedList`, is collection of `nodes`. NODE are separated into 2 parts like:

```
NODE
+-------------------------------+
| data | Reference to other node|
+-------------------------------+
```

so data can be anything a `primitive` datatype or an `Object` but the reference is always the `Node`
So in the example below:

```
public class SLLNode<E> {
    protected E element;
    protected SLLNode<E> next;
}
```

Here the name of the Node is `SLLNode` and that Node there are `2 members` one is the data i.e `Element` and other is the reference to the other node i.e `SLLNODE` which will look like:

```
NODE
+-------------------------------+
| Element  | SLLNODE            |
+-------------------------------+
```

As the name says reference to the other node is holding on to the reference of the other node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`element` is the value of the node, and `next` is the reference to the next node. That's the textbook example of a linked list.